# Google Now integration with Ford

Tags: bluetooth, google-now, voice-recognition, voice-command

I am attempting to get my Android Phone (not Google Auto) to cooperate more with my Ford.

At the moment, I can use the phone to connect by Bluetooth to play music, do voice calls and the usual things. I would however, like to be able to hands-free (or using the steering wheel button to) tell my phone to do something whilst I am driving.

For example, if I am navigating. I might like to know when I will reach my destination.

Typically, what will happen is my phone is in my pocket with the screen off. So it cannot hear me say OK Google. However, even if I leave my phone somewhere secure with the screen on, it is torturous to get it to respond to OK Google. I am assuming that the OK Google system is not listening passively through the Bluetooth system.

Ideally, I would like Google Now to be activated with the voice button on the steering wheel. However, OK Google would be great too.

My phone:

- Nexus 5
- Android Marshmallow 6.0.1
- Stock OTA Rom

My car:

- Ford Galaxy
- Cannot find version of the Ford computer